# Cannot read property 'container' of null when using linkTo helper in an Ember template

Tags: ember.js

I am creating an Ember application as an add-on to some HTML returned from the server. I need this HTML so that the site can be indexed by search engines, and also to speed up the initial page rendering for the users.

So my application consists of several Ember Views, appended to different DOM elements of the HTML generated by the server. I don't use master templates for routes, so I set renderTemplate function of each route to do nothing.

My Ember App is bound to body element and I can successfully append a custom view to an element down the tree. It works:

**[In this JSFiddle three last elements of the list are appended by Ember](http://jsfiddle.net/6cBRx/4/)**

But when I try to use linkTo helper in my template, I hit an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of null ember-latest.js:32224
```

which is in this function:

```
router: Ember.computed(function() {
     return get(this, 'controller').container.lookup('router:main');
}),
```

**[In this JS fiddle I just add linkTo to the template, and it breaks everything](http://jsfiddle.net/6cBRx/3/)**

1. In general, can Ember work this way - having many Views scattered
   over the HTML rendered by the server?
2. How can the example code be
   fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I need to additionally bind the view and the container together to make this fiddle work

```
  App.itemsView.set("controller", App.itemsController);
  App.itemsController.set("container", this.container);
```

So the resulting working code snippet is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ddegtyarev/6cBRx/6/

Again, let me reiterate that I'm building an hybrid Ember application - i.e. I have some HTML returned right from the server, and some appended by multiple Ember views in multiple places. This is why I have to manually create the views and bind them with controllers etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hyder1920/6cBRx/5/), Check it out.

Seems like you are starter to Ember,
So here are some tips for you,

1. You should have an `application` template, which will be the root template and on which all the templates will be rendered.
2. You shouldn't access `views` using `this.container.lookup`, that is for debugging only.
3. You shouldn't append `views` to the DOM, it's the job of the **framework** to do.
4. By default your application will be appended to the body of the html, if you want it to be appended elsewhere, give the `rootElement` property when creating the `application`. Refer [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html) for configuring your `application`.

> The rootElement can be either a DOM element or a jQuery-compatible selector string. Note that views appended to the DOM outside the root element will not receive events. If you specify a custom root element, make sure you only append views inside it!
>
> Don't access any controllers globally like `App.itemsController.set("content", model)`, if you want to access another `controller` inside a route, use `this.controllerFor`, and to access inside another `controller`, use `needs`.
>
> You need not create any controller instance like `App.itemsController=Ember.ArrayController.extend({}).create();`
>   The **framework** will take care of all these.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The link to fiddle you've sent is actually my broken fiddle, so I can't see your solution. I used to have a few Ember apps on the page, but then I decided to try to have one app with many views, manually appended to the **HTML returned by the server**. That is why I can't follow the default path of using Ember

Comment: Oops ! Sorry, forgot to update the fiddle, after editing it.
Now changed the fiddle link, you can check now.
If you want to have more than one Ember app in a page, you can achieve  it using the `rootElement` property. But manually appending views is not a good solution IMO.